# grunt command not found after installed grunt and grunt cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed grunt and grunt cli, but still I got command not found error

```
{
  "name": "angulartdd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

I can try to install grunt globally but I want to know why this isn't working.

Comment: You **need** to install grunt globally (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli)

Comment: @myhau I did and it says unable to find local grunt?

Comment: Do `npm install` inside directory that contains `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I installed grunt globally and it worked.

```
npm install -g grunt
```